# The reason of 0 backtest data in my pinescript code

Tags: pine-script

First of all, sorry for the bad English.

I'm making some strategy using S/R line and RSI.

However, after finishing the work, I realized that there is 0 backtest trade in my work.

I'm not sure about the reason, but maybe there are some errors in my script. So I'm asking your help.

Would  you check any error codes in my script? I'll post the part of mine.

```
//strategy//

if (not na(vrsi))
    if(co and resistancebroken)
        strategy.entry(id="buy", long=true, comment="Long")

if(strategy.position_size>0)
    if(longstoploss_level)
        strategy.close(id="buy", comment="StopLoss")
    if(supportbroken and close>strategy.position_avg_price)
        strategy.close(id="buy", comment="Long End")

if (not na(vrsi))
    if(cu and supportbroken)
        strategy.entry(id="short", long=false, comment="Short")

if(strategy.position_size<0)
    if(shortstoploss_level)
        strategy.close(id="short", comment="StopLoss")
    if(resistancebroken and close<strategy.position_avg_price)
        strategy.close(id="short", comment="Short End")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without full code. First of all, you need to change excessive multiple `if` blocks to single ones.

```
if (not na(vrsi))
    if(co and resistancebroken)
        strategy.entry(id="buy", long=true, comment="Long")
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
LongCondition = not na(vrsi) and co and resistancebroken
if LongCondition
    strategy.entry(id="buy", long=true, comment="Long")
```

After than you can

```
plot(LongCondition? 1 : 0)
```

to see whether your condition is is true. (probably you will be getting 0, so you have to review your enter conditions by plotting

```
plot(not na(vrsi) ? 1 : 0)
plot(co ? 1 : 0)
plot(resistancebroken ? 1 : 0)
```

and then decide which one is broken.

Same apply for your `short` and `close` conditions.